# How to make a reference point to the address of primitive and access it through the member?

Tags: javascript, reference, primitive

```
export function createZeroVector(){
    let out = [0, 0, 0]
    out.x = out[0]
    out.y = out[1]
    out.z = out[2]
    return out
}
```

I created a vec3 domain as shown above, and I want to x, y, and z to point to 0th, 1st, and 2nd indexes of the array respectively. But in that case that I've written, since the array consists of primitives; x, y, and z will not be designated as a reference so if I will make changes in the future, x, y, and z remain the same that is not that I want. So how can I overcome that issue?

e.g if I will change out[0], then someVec3.x must be changed.

Comment: "*So how can I overcome that issue?*" what are you even trying to do that requires references? There are (kind of, sort of) no references in JS. Not for primitives, at the very least. There is no way to keep primitive values synced across multiple data structures. You can hack something together with proxies and a lot of dodgy code but it's better to stick to actually using the language normally.

Comment: @VLAZ no proxies required for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not have references.

For object properties, you can however overcome this with getters/setters:

```
const xyzDescriptors = {
    x: {
        get() { return this[0]; },
        set(v) { this[0] = v; },
    },
    y: {
        get() { return this[1]; },
        set(v) { this[1] = v; },
    },
    z: {
        get() { return this[2]; },
        set(v) { this[2] = v; },
    },
};
export function createZeroVector() {
    return Object.defineProperties([0, 0, 0], xyzDescriptors);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this

```
const xyz = ["x", "y", "z"];
var out = [8, 20, 0];

function hasProps(obj, propsList, prop) {
  if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, prop, {
      get: function() {
        return obj[propsList.indexOf(prop)];

      }
    });
  }
}
xyz.forEach(function(key, index, array) {
  hasProps(out, array, key)
});

console.log(out.x);// logs '8'
console.log(out.y);// logs '20'
console.log(out.z);// logs '0'
```

```js
const xyz = ["x", "y", "z"];
var out = [8, 20, 0];

function hasProps(obj, propsList, prop) {
  if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, prop, {
      get: function() {
        return obj[propsList.indexOf(prop)];

      }
    });
  }
}
xyz.forEach(function(key, index, array) {
  hasProps(out, array, key)
});

console.log(out.x); // logs '8'
console.log(out.y); // logs '20'
console.log(out.z); // logs '0'
```